# Combobox Validations using error provider

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

hi i have a combobox in my windows application. I have seen validations done using error provider control.But the problem with that is the tell to set the selected Index to 0.
where as my selected index i have set to -1. how to provide validations for a combobox

Comment: Show your work and tell people what have you tried so far..

Comment: the question is not clear at all...

Comment: ErrorProvider doesn't validate anything, it just reports errors.  If you don't like -1 for the SelectedIndex then change the combo's DropDownStyle to DropDownList.  Or display an error.